# Update main form after another form is closed

Tags: java, forms

I'm working on an application which is coded in Java. It reads **calibration values for later calculations from** .xml file on first initialization. Values can be later modified and saved to an `xml` file from another form called 'Properties', that is opened from the Main form.

How can I notify the Main form after the 'Properties' form is closed to read new modified values from `.xml` file?  Or is there a better way to exchange this data and I should not read .xml again after?

Answer (score 0):

Without more information about how your forms are set up it's hard to give a true answer.

Create an object set up to hold the information you will read from the .xml file. In Main, have one (or more as necessary) of these objects. Store the information from the .xml file into it. Pass and update that data object in Properties form, and have it be returned. After you're done editing, fire a propertyChange or call a method which will trigger tell Main to read from the data store object.

If you want to stick with re-reading the .xml file upon closing the Properties form, then you would need to edit the window/form closing procedure (depends on how your form is set up). If the Properties form is a JFrame, then there should be a "windowClosing" method that can be written for it.